# POST Method not working in CGI

Tags: html, forms, apache, shell, cgi

I am writing a CGI script with Shell as basic language and with HTML and JavaScript in it. I am using Apache server and my OS is Ubuntu Server 14.01.1.

There are multiple purposes of this script as well as it's too big so I wont be sharing it here or explaining it fully. In a nutshell, I have a form in which I am validating fields, accepting values in Shell variables and then substituting them in a shell script which also runs in a CGI file when I click submit button. Now the issue here is there are fields whose data is sensitive as a result I MUST use the `POST` form method.

My CGI script works perfectly fine with `GET` method however with `POST`, It just does not connect to next page. Right now, It is linked to a simple web page with no scripting or dynamic building. I instantly get the error `Connection Reset By Peer`. When I checked apache error log, I get the error `Failed to flush CGI output to client`.

I just can't find a way around this error. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: "Now the issue here is there are fields whose data is sensitive as a result I MUST use the POST form method." — POST adds virtually nothing in the way of security.

Comment: "it's too big so I wont be sharing it here or explaining it fully" — See   http://sscce.org/ — You need to explain it enough for people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin, I am well aware of that. However, There is no point in making passwords or stuff visible in address bar of the browser. Hence `POST`..